# Overriding JSON encoder in Flask 3.0, json_encoder deprecated?

Tags: flask

According to the Flask 3.0 release notes:

> json_encoder and json_decoder attributes on app and blueprint, and the corresponding json.JSONEncoder and JSONDecoder classes, are removed.

I need to serialize an ObjectID into str within my app, which i used to do via:

```
class JSONEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        # objectID
        if isinstance(o, ObjectId):
            return str(o)
        # datetime
        if isinstance(o, datetime.datetime):
            return str(o)

        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, o)
```

and

```
app.json_encoder = JSONEncoder
```

how are people doing it now?

Comment: you might want to take a look at marshmallow (https://flask-marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for serializing and deserializing data

Comment: json_encoder and json_decoder have been deprecated in favour of a single json provider interface. See https://github.com/pallets/flask/pull/4692  for details. It shouldn’t take much work to update your class accordingly.